# Size of child in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am using react with firebase realtime database

[image: Firebase data structure]

So i have this firebase data and i want to count total values in followers. However, what i know is that firebase do not have such a function to count and you need to manually do it.

From below i can see all the user data such as username and email. However, i still cannot figure out how to count the number of followers.

I hope someone can help. Thank you.

```
const ref = firebaseDB.ref();
ref
  .child("Users")
  .orderByChild("email")
  .equalTo(this.state.currentUserEmail)
  .once("value", snapshot => {
    let userData = {};
    for (var childSnapshot in snapshot.val()) {
      userData.key = childSnapshot;
      // then loop through the keys inside the child object and get the values like price (key) : 44.95 (value)
      for (var value in snapshot.val()[childSnapshot]) {
        console.log(value);
        console.log(snapshot.val()[childSnapshot][value]);
        userData[value] = snapshot.val()[childSnapshot][value];
      }
    }
    console.log(userData);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
const ref = firebaseDB.ref();
ref
  .child("Users")
  .orderByChild("email")
  .equalTo(this.state.currentUserEmail)
  .once("value", snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      console.log(childSnapshot.child("followers").numChildren());
    }
    console.log(userData);
  });
```

The changes/additions:

1. Use `DataSnapshot.forEach()` for a cleaner way to loop over the children.
2. Use `DataSnapshot.child()` to get the snapshot for the `followers` node.
3. Use `DataSnapshot.numChildren()` to determine the number of followers.